# how to list nfts in NFT marketplace with my custom token

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix, nft, smart-contract-wallets

I want to build an marketplace to sell nfts and only accept my own custom token as a payment method the way Decentraland has mana as their token below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6y9D.png

I could create my own token like so:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Shiaf is ERC20 {
    constructor() ERC20("Shiaf", "MTK") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 10000000 * 10 ** decimals());
    }
}
```

But I want all payments on the website marketplace to be in the custom token

Comment: You can look at Decentraland contracts for a start

Comment: Where can I find that please?

Comment: This maybe https://github.com/decentraland/marketplace-contracts